# Unable to connect to CMS from Workflow Designer

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, visio-designer

I am unable to connect to CMS from Workflow Designer client and getting below error message:

**"The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. System.Web.Services()."**

We have configured CMS with the LDAP authentication and with same LDAP credentials I am able to connect to CME, Template Builder, Content Porter.

Please let me know what could be the issue or where to find the more detail? (FYI, Event Viewer of the CMS server doesn't have any such error reported).

Comment: Which version of Visio you are using and whether it is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Also, is it possible to test for you to connect by installing the Visio on the CMS server? Further, what is there in the event log?

Comment: I am using 32 bit visio,addition to this while checking response from fiddler I can see wflistener.asmx throws unauthorised error. Do we need to make some additional settings for wflistener virtual directory with LDAP authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I get the solution by making Authentication setting to "Anonymous Authentication: Enabled" and rest of them disabled under "WFListener" virtual directory on the IIS.